# Tungsten Halogen Globes

Tags: electromagnetism

The tool shed of my current residence has holes in it, and it rained heavily the last few weeks, during which the expected outcome of one of my flood lights blowing a fuse occurred.

I don't want to waste money replicating the scenario, but I am curious as to ask is the colour spectrum for the blown globe is purely coincidental, or is it an expected outcome?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Due to high-temperature glass (4000 ‘F filament). Any dust, finger-skin-oil, can cause thermal stress or water drops can cool glass, lower resistance and draw more current blowing fuse or excess heat in a closed enclosure with reduced life span will sputter tungsten inside the glass when it fuses open.

I’m surprised the glass didn’t break, if it got wet, but perhaps it didn't and rain was coincidental.  Start current  when cold is 3kW and steady  state hot is 300W.  Divide by /x for lower power bulbs but all tungsten filaments are about 10:1 cold:hot resistance and power consumption.

It's a fact that lifespan of any tungsten bulb can be extended **greatly** by even cooling it 50 to 100'C degrees down inside the luminaire for convection air flow.

Comment: Yes it was enclosed within protective fixture, the flood lights are very cheap presumably due to the amount of heat they dissipate requiring additional safety precautions. I haven't opened any of it up yet to take a look, but I just found it so odd in regard to the colouring as seen in the photo I put up, the globe's glass was completely transparent prior to blowing

Comment: "*Start current when cold is 3kW ..*"?

Comment: Yes the start current draws 3kW for a 300W bulb @TrAnSiStOr

Comment: @Adam what fuse did it blow or did you mean it fused open the bulb. that's normal if it was enclosed ( excess heat) instead of ambient convection cooled with a crystal glass protector from the explosive glass that can occur with a drop of water and perhaps had nothing to with the leaky roof.

Comment: Sorry no like I said I haven't got round to cracking it open yet I just assumed a fuse to be a part of power board circuitry because it made no sound nor did I experience any of the other forms of punishment that accompany a lack of regard for safety protocol when using electricity

Comment: It's mainly the precise spectral line of colours that has me head scratching I mean if its just pretty coincidence fine I concede defeat but if not it could be a pretty easy spectrometer in the making. Well relatively I mean, as far as making spectrometers are concerned

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 yeah they are quite bizzare arnt they, in the manual for the light I was reading that the lifetime of the bulb will be shortened significantly just by standing the light on its side

Comment: The filament is over 4000’K but the glass must be cooled by convection air as Arrhenius Law Controls the MTBF every 10’C rise. THat means on half power it will last many years but not on 10% for Halogen recombination to work properly.